# React - All of my values are getting populated with a switch statement when only one at a time should

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am working on a portfolio project that is an emulator of Wordle.

I am trying to populate one square at a time with a letter that corresponds to the button a user presses. The issue that I am having comes from the fact that when a user presses a button it does not populate one of the squares with the input but it populates all of the squares.

I am using React, Next.JS and Bootstrap 5.

The following is the section of code dealing with buttons.

```
   <div id="key-row" class="row">
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="Q" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('Q')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Q</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="W" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('W')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">W</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="E" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('E')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">E</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="R" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('R')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">R</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="T" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('T')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">T</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="Y" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('Y')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Y</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="U" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('U')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">U</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="I" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('I')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">I</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="O" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('O')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">O</button>
    </div>
    <div id="key-col" class="col">
      <button value="P" onClick={() => this.handleTextChange('P')} id="keyboard-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">P</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The following code deals with handling the button presses and populating the squares.

```
export default class Gameboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.rowNumber = 1;
    this.colNumber = 1;
  }

  handleTextChange = (letter) => {
    switch('row' + this.rowNumber + 'col' + this.colNumber) {
      case 'row1col1':
        this.setState({row1col1: letter});
      case 'row1col2':
        this.setState({row1col2: letter});
      case 'row1col3':
        this.setState({row1col3: letter});
      case 'row1col4':
        this.setState({row1col4: letter});
      case 'row1col5':
        this.setState({row1col5: letter});
      case 'row2col1':
        this.setState({row2col1: letter});
      case 'row2col2':
        this.setState({row2col2: letter});
      case 'row2col3':
        this.setState({row2col3: letter});
      case 'row2col4':
        this.setState({row2col4: letter});
      case 'row2col5':
        this.setState({row2col5: letter});
      default:
          this.setState({'': ''});
    }
  }
```

The following code are my buttons.

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="game-box" class="container">
          <div id="row" class="row">
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row1col1}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row1col2}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row1col3}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row1col4}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row1col5}</p></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="row" class="row">
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row2col1}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row2col2}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row2col3}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row2col4}</p></div>
              </div>
              <div id="col" class="col">
                <div id="box"><p id="entry">{this.state.row2col5}</p></div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

How do I fix the duplication issue that I am facing?

Images of the issue:
As you can see every box gets populated with a letter. It should be one box at a time as the user presses different buttons.

[image]

Comment: I see 2 things that may go wrong: 1. The rowNumber and colNumber state is never updated so it keeps default values of `1`. 2. Missing `break;` statement in between the cases of the `switch` statement

Comment: @Jhilton Im in disbelief. I cant belive I forgot the breaks and that after an hour I didnt notice it. Appreciate your help. Fixing this resolved the issue.

Comment: What you are doing is a bit crazy btw, this should be represented as a multidimensional array.

Comment: I dont have a lot of experience with React or JS so I wasn't sure how to implement something like that.

Comment: I thought JS didn't support multidimensional arrays natively. I guess array of arrays?